# MySQL query not executing in phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Using phalcon framework

The purpose of this mysql query is to return the comment count on a forum within the last 1 day:

```
SELECT fc.forum_id, count( fc.forum_id ) AS total_comments
FROM forum_comments AS fc
WHERE DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1
DAY ) <= fc.updated_at
GROUP BY fc.forum_id
ORDER BY total_comments DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It will run correctly in phpmyadmin but phalcon throws:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sidra\app\controllers\ApiController.php on line 810 Syntax error, unexpected token INTEGER(1), near to ' DAY ) <= fc.updated_at GROUP BY fc.forum_id ORDER BY total_comments DESC ', when parsing: SELECT fc.forum_id,count(fc.forum_id)as total_comments FROM ForumComments as fc WHERE DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) <= fc.updated_at GROUP BY fc.forum_id ORDER BY total_comments DESC (215)

My phalcon codes:

```
$sql = "SELECT fc.forum_id,count(fc.forum_id)as total_comments ".
                "FROM ForumComments as fc ".
                "WHERE DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1
                 DAY ) <= fc.updated_at ".
                "GROUP BY fc.forum_id ".
                "ORDER BY total_comments DESC ";

        $query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql);
        $staff = $query->execute()->toArray();
```

If there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Looks like there's a query parsing error. I'd hit the phalcon doco to find out about query parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is correct and works fine on MySQL versions from 4.1 to 5.6.6. So it seems that `createQuery()` method is trying to parse the query and fails on the `INTERVAL` clause. I would recommend you to try something like this:

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days"));

$sql = "SELECT fc.forum_id,count(fc.forum_id)as total_comments ".
            "FROM ForumComments as fc ".
            "WHERE '$yesterday' <= fc.updated_at ".
            "GROUP BY fc.forum_id ".
            "ORDER BY total_comments DESC ";

$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql);
$staff = $query->execute()->toArray();
```